# I am having npm version 8.1.2 but I want to install npm version 5.5.1

Tags: node.js, npm, backend, npm-install, npm-init

Currently , I am having npm version 8 but I want to have npm 5.5.1 ,
Last time also I did npm i -g@5.5.1 this but I **struggled** through the module not found **error** , and finally I **resolved** but now I want to install **lower** **version** i.e 5.5.1 , please tell me **the exact/correct** steps for **windows**.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install -g npm@5.5.1
```

Try this

Comment: As mentioned  , I did this only before but it not got installed and I was getting
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
Require stack:

this error, so now I don't wanna take risks

Comment: yarn global add npm - use this command to globally install npm using yarn

Comment: For windows yarn is not compatible ig?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

You need to install `npm-windows-upgrade`

then use `npm-windows-upgrade --npm version 5.5.1`

Reference: [upgrade npm on windows](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade#upgrade-npm-on-windows)